# why can't we declare functions inside a structure?

Tags: c, function, struct, declaration

I read plenty of questions regarding

> `declaration of functions inside structure?`

But I did not get a satisfactory answer.

My question is not about `whether functions can be declared inside a structure or not?`

Instead, my question is

> **`WHY function can not be declared inside structure?`**

Comment: Because these are the rules you need to follow if you want to play with `C`.

Comment: What would it mean? A structure is a template for data, it doesn't specify the values.

Comment: You can have function _pointers_ in structures.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well that is the fundamental difference between C and C++ (works in C++). C++ supports classes (and in C++ a `struct` is a special case of a class), and C does not.

In C you would implement the class as a structure with functions that take a `this` pointer explicitly, which is essentially what C++ does under the hood. Coupled with a sensible naming convention so you know what functions belong to which classes (again something C++ does under then hood with name-mangling), you get close to object-based if not object-oriented programming. For example:

```
typedef struct temp
{
    int a;

} classTemp ;

void classTemp_GetData( classTemp* pThis )
{
    printf( "Enter value of a : " );
    scanf( "%d", &(pThis->a) );
}

classTemp T ;

int main()
{
    classTemp_GetData( &T );
}
```

However, as you can see without language support for classes, implementing then can become tiresome.

In C, the functions and data structures are more or less bare; the language gives a minimum of support for combining data structures together, and none at all (directly) for including functions with those data structures.

The purpose of C is to have a language that translates as directly as possible into machine code, more like a portable assembly language than a higher-level language such as C++ (not that C++ is all that high-level). C let's you get very close to the machine, getting into details that most languages abstract away; the down side of this is that you have to get close to the machine in C to use the language to its utmost. It takes a completely different approach to programming from C++, something that the surface similarities between them hide.

Check out [here](http://forums.devshed.com/c-programming-42/declaring-function-in-structure-in-c-545529.html) for more info (wonderful discussions there).

---

**P.S.:** You can also accomplish the functionality by using function pointers, i.e.
have a pointer to a function (as a variable) inside the `struct`.

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct t {
    int a;
    void (*fun) (int * a);        // <-- function pointers
} ;

void get_a (int * a) {
    printf (" input : ");
    scanf ("%d", a);
}

int main () {
    struct t test;
    test.a = 0;

    printf ("a (before): %d\n", test.a);
    test.fun = get_a;
    test.fun(&test.a);
    printf ("a (after ): %d\n", test.a);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> WHY function can not be declared inside structure?

Because C standard does not allow to declare function/method inside a structure. C is not object-oriented language.

#### 6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers:

> **A structure or union shall not contain a member with incomplete or function type**(hence,
> a structure shall not contain an instance of itself, but may contain a pointer to an instance
> of itself), except that the last member of a structure with more than one named member
> may have incomplete array type; such a structure (and any union containing, possibly
> recursively, a member that is such a structure) shall not be a member of a structure or an
> element of an array.

Comment: isn't there a specific reason for that?

Comment: This is the reason. Note that in C++, you can declare a function inside a structure. But in C, it's like asking why you can't declare a function in the middle of an expression, or inside another function.

Comment: This is disingenuous. I think he wants to know why the C standard doesn't allow it. It doesn't because it doesn't is not much help.

Comment: Quoting the standard doesn't improve the answer, unless you quote the rationale document.

Comment: We're not children, "because I said so" doesn't cut it.

Comment: @Barmar; Rules are rules. If standard says you can't then you can't.

Comment: But the language designers have reasons for making the rules, they're not usually just arbitrary decisions.

Comment: @Barmar; Then I ask you why C has no objects?

Comment: Because C isn't an object-oriented language.

Comment: @Barmar; Why isn't it?

Comment: Because K&R were designing a very simple language, that could be compiled easily into very efficient code, and the mapping from source code to object code would be fairly obvious. Object-oriented features would have complicated this.

Comment: If you want C to have a lot of extra features, you might want C++ instead. (Note that you can write code very similar to C in C++, and only use those extra features you want)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose there were and are many reasons, here are several of them:

1. C programming language was created in 1972, and was influenced by pure assembly language, so struct was supposed as "data-only" element
2. As soon as C is NOT object oriented language - there is actually no sense to define functions inside "data structure", there are no such entity as constructor/method etc
3. Functions are directly translated to pure assembly `push` and `call` instructions and there are no hidden arguments like `this`

Answer (score 0):

I guess, because it wouldn't make much sence in C. If you declare a function inside structure, you expect it to be somehow related to that structure, right? Say,

```
struct A {
  int foo;
  void hello() {
    // smth
  }
}
```

Would you expect `hello()` to have access to `foo` at least? Because otherwise `hello()` only got something like namespace, so to call it we would write `A.hello()` - it would be a static function, in terms of C++ - not much difference from normal C function.

If `hello()` has access to `foo`, there must be a `this` pointer to implement such access, which in C++ always implicitly passed to functions as first argument.
If a structure function has access to structure variables, it must be different somehow from access that have other functions, again, to add some sence to functions inside structures at all. So we have `public`, `private` modificators.

Next. You don't have inheritance in C (but you can simulate it), and this is something that adds lots of sence to declaring functions inside structutes. So here we'd like to add `virtual` and `protected`.

Now you can add namespaces and classes, and here you are, invented C++ (well, without templates).

But C++ is object-oriented, and C is not. First, people created C, then they wrote tons of programs, understood some improvements that could be made, and then, following reasonings that I mentioned earlier, they came up with C++. They did not change C instead to separate concepts - C is procedure-oriented, and C++ is object-oriented.

Answer (score 0):

C was designed so that it could be processed with a relatively simple compilation system.  To allow function definitions to appear within anything else would have required the compiler to keep track of the context in which the function appeared while processing it.  Given that members of a structure, union, or enum declaration do not enter scope until the end of the declaration, there would be nothing that a function declared within a structure could do which a function declared elsewhere could not.

Conceptually, it might have been nice to allow constant declarations within a structure; a constant pointer to a literal function would then be a special case of that (even if the function itself had to be declared elsewhere), but that would have required the C compiler to keep track of more information for each structure member--not just its type and its offset, but also whether it was a constant and, if so, what its value should be.  Such a thing would not be difficult in today's compilation environments, but early C compilers were expected to run with orders of magnitude less memory than would be available today.

Given that C has been extended to offer many features which could not very well be handled by a compiler running on a 64K (or smaller) system, it might reasonably be argued that it should no longer be bound by such constraints.  Indeed, there are some aspect of C's heritage which I would like to lose, such as the integer-promotion rules which require even new integer types to follow the inconsistent rules for old types, rather than allowing the new types to have explicitly specified behavior [e.g. have a `wrap32_t` which could be converted to any other integer type without a typecast, but when added to any "non-wrap" integer type *of any size* would yield a `wrap32_t`].  Being able to define functions within a struct might be nice, but it would be pretty far down on my list of improvements.